# ¿Cómo encontrar letras iguales consecutivas en una matriz de java?

Tags: java

a ver si me puedo explicar bien: lo que necesito hacer es encontrar letras iguales de manera horizontal o vertical en una matriz de 6x6 las letras pueden ser T,G,A ó C lo que debería encontrar seria: AAAA ó GGGG ó TTTT ó CCCC, como dije de manera horizontal o vertical (no hacer falta de manera diagonal), dejo una imagen de ejemplo y también el código que tengo hasta ahora, que si bien me recorre fila a fila y columna a columna no logro que me busque la secuencia. Perdón si no me explico bien lo que pasa que es muy largo. desde ya gracias!!!
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[][] matriz;
    int i, j, contadorHorizontal, contadorVertical, contadorDiagonal, contadorGeneral;
    boolean cadenaHorizontal, cadenaVertical, cadenaDiagonal;

    String elementoAnteriorFilas, elementoAnteriorColumnas;

    matriz = new String[][]{{"A", "T", "G", "C", "G", "A"}, {"C", "A", "G", "T", "G", "C"}, {"T", "T", "A", "T", "G", "T"}, {"A", "G", "A", "A", "G", "G"}, {"C", "C", "C", "C", "T", "A"}, {"T", "C", "A", "C", "T", "G"}};

    //esto recorre la matriz
    for (i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < matriz[0].length; j++) {

            System.out.print(matriz[i][j]);
            System.out.print(" ");

        }
        System.out.println(" ");
    }

    //busco en el sentido de las lineas
    for (i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {

        cadenaHorizontal = false;
        contadorHorizontal = 0;

        for (j = 0; j < matriz[0].length; j++) {

            if (matriz[i][j].equals("A") || matriz[i][j].equals("T") || matriz[i][j].equals("C") || matriz[i][j].equals("G")) {

                elementoAnteriorFilas = matriz[i][j];

                if (elementoAnteriorFilas == matriz[i][j]) {

                    contadorHorizontal++;

                    if (contadorHorizontal == 4) {

                        cadenaHorizontal = true;

                    }
                }
            }

        }
        System.out.println(cadenaHorizontal);

    }
    System.out.println("");

    //busco en el sentido de las columnas
    for (j = 0; j < matriz[0].length; j++) {
        contadorVertical = 0;
        cadenaVertical = false;

        for (i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {

            if (matriz[i][j].equals("A") || matriz[i][j].equals("T") || matriz[i][j].equals("C") || matriz[i][j].equals("G")) {

                elementoAnteriorColumnas = matriz[i][j];

                if (elementoAnteriorColumnas.equals(matriz[i][j])) {

                    contadorVertical++;

                    if (contadorVertical >= 4) {

                        cadenaVertical = true;
                    }

                }

            }

        }
        System.out.println(cadenaVertical);

    }
    System.out.println("");

    //busco en el sentido de las diagonales
}   //aca también me trabe
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seria mucho mejor comentar tu codigo para entender que haces. Sin embargo, esto es muy facil de solucionar sin hacer tanto lio...

Si vos queres que cuatro celdas consecutivas tengan el mismo valor entonces lo unico que tenes que comprobar es si 4 celdas consecutivas, son iguales.. no?

para eso, alcanza con recorrer de la siguiente manera:

```
for (i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
    //vamos hasta -3, porque ir mas alla no sirve porque no hay 4 elementos
    for (j = 0; j < matriz[0].length-3; j++) {

        if (matriz[i][j] == matriz[i][j+1] 
            && matriz[i][j] == matriz[i][j+2]
            && matriz[i][j] == matriz[i][j+3])
            {
                //Encontramos 4 iguales!!!!
                //hacemos lo que haga falta
            }
    }
}
```

Ahora, para los columnas es exactamente igual pero invirtiendo los indices (en lugar de [i][j] es [j][i]) y si quisieras diagonales, tambien se puede hacer usando [i][j] -> [i+1][j+1])